# How to use Mersenne Twister to generate all values between two numbers exactly once

Tags: c++, algorithm, random, mersenne-twister

I would like to use mt19937 to loop over an array and grab each value from it exactly once, but in a random order. Essentially, is there a way to use mt19937 to generate all numbers within a particular range exactly once (without just ignoring duplicates, but ensuring that it does not produce duplicates altogether(for the sake of efficiency))?

I have considered a shuffle function, however it's only the indices I care about; the values within the array are arbitrary, but their corresponding index is important. I have a matrix of 1's and I need to randomly select an index and turn that 1 to a 0. But I don't want to perform this calculation more than is necessary (exactly as many elements as are in the matrix).

Comment: Look at `shuffle`.

Comment: Have you made an attempt at solving this problem yourself? Also, this problem is not specific to the specific random number engine you're using (mt19937).

Comment: Random numbers generate duplicates, otherwise they wouldn't be random. I second @Jarod42 suggestion to look into [`std::shuffle`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/random_shuffle).

Comment: From what I read, Mersenne Twister is limited to ranges based on 2^n - 1. Depending on the range, there may be a [LCG](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_congruential_generator) multiplier, increment value, and modulus that would work.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your array is of size `N` and you don't want to rearrange it:

1. Generate a second array, also of size `N`.
2. Shuffle the second array using the [Fisher-Yates-Knuth shuffle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle).
3. Utilize the elements of the first array in the order specified by the second array.

The Fisher-Yates-Knuth shuffle can be implemented as follows:

```
//To shuffle an array a of n elements (indices 0..n-1):
for i from 0 to n−2 do
  j ← random integer such that i ≤ j < n
  swap a[i] and a[j]
```

You could also use [`std::shuffle`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/shuffle/):

```
std::shuffle(a.begin(), a.end(), std::default_random_engine(seed));
```

Answer (score 0):

So you need to create a list of values, then shuffle them.

Whilst there's a function to shuffle, the algorithm is simple. Start at index 0 and swap with a random value in the range 0 to N-1, then go to index 1 and swap with a random value in the range 1 to N-1, and so on, Don't swap on 0 to N-1 as that doesn't provide a genuinely random permutation.

Comment: I considered a shuffle function, but it's actually only the indices I care about; the values within the array are arbitrary, but their corresponding index is important. Essentially, I have a matrix of 1's and I need to randomly select an index and turn that 1 to a 0. But I don't want to perform this calculation more than is necessary (exactly as many elements as are in the matrix). I realise now that my original question was quite poorly worded, sorry.